# DWA suddenly stops when it arrives to the goal

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using move_base and dwa_local_planner. Robot moves smoothly at start but when it arrives to goal it suddenly stops instead of slowing down when getting closer to the goal. I have tried different acceleration values but it didn't effect the behavior. My planner parameters are set like this

```
DWAPlannerROS:
  max_vel_trans: 1.0
  min_vel_trans: 0.1

  max_vel_x: 1.0
  min_vel_x: -1.0
  max_vel_theta: 1.0 
  min_vel_theta: 0.1 
  max_vel_y: 0.0
  min_vel_y: 0.0
    
  acc_lim_x: 0.15
  acc_lim_y: 0.0
  acc_lim_theta: 0.35
  acc_lim_trans: 0.15
  prune_plane: true  

  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.5
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 6.28
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

  sim_time: 1.5
  sim_granularity: 0.1
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.1
  vx_samples: 20
  vy_samples: 1
  vth_samples: 20

  path_distance_bias: 32.0
  goal_distance_bias: 15.0
  occdist_scale: 0.02
  forward_point_distance: 0.325
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2
  scaling_speed: 0.25
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05

  publish_traj_pc : true
  publish_cost_grid_pc: true
  controller_frequency: 1.0
```

Example of this behavior can be seen from rqt plots

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

Edit 1: I have noticed that yaw goal tolerance is too high which prevents rotating_to_goal behavior in computeVelocityCommandsStopRotate function at the end and directly sets cmd_vel to 0. However, it still doesn't fix sudden stop problem if the goal yaw and final position yaw is in the given tolerance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384131/dwa-suddenly-stops-when-it-arrives-to-the-goal/) by [rappy](https://answers.ros.org/users/76966/rappy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-08-11**:
Why do we not see cmd_vel.linear.x in these plots? What is the black line?

**Comment by [rappy](https://answers.ros.org/users/76966/rappy/) on 2021-08-12**:
Black line is cmd_vel actually I have changed the plot style manually but I think rqt didn't update the legend

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-08-12**:
A couple thoughts on your DWAPlanner config:

Your `controller_frequency` is insanely low, and is not consistent with the black dots in first plot. Most people prefer to inherit this rate from the parent move_base.

Under normal circumstances, DWAPlanner will linearly ramp the x velocity down to 0 once it is a certain distance from the goal. Your very low `acc_lim_x` and very short `stop_time_buffer` might be interfering with this ramp-down mechanism.

**Comment by [rappy](https://answers.ros.org/users/76966/rappy/) on 2021-08-13**:
You are right I forgot to remove `controller frequency` parameter from this config and it is set to 15 in move_base config. So I have changed the parameters you have suggested to and it fixed the problem. Thanks for the advice.

```
acc_lim_trans: 0.3
acc_lim_x: 0.3
stop_time_buffer: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A couple thoughts on your DWAPlanner config:

Your `controller_frequency` is insanely low, and is not consistent with the black dots in first plot. Most people prefer to inherit this rate from the parent move_base.

Under normal circumstances, DWAPlanner will linearly ramp the x velocity down to 0 once it is a certain distance from the goal. Your very low `acc_lim_x` and very short `stop_time_buffer` might be interfering with this ramp-down mechanism.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1